# Bat file: code to execute all files within folder in alphabetic order

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line, command, batch-processing

I am launching an application with parameters in this way:

```
application.exe /in:"c:folder\filename1.txt" --log
application.exe /in:"c:folder\filename2.txt" --log
```

And that runs the first instance, waits for it to finish and then runs the second.

How can I programmatically  run all the files within 'folder' in alphabetic order (Keeping the same "wait and go" logic) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the command line: `for %f in (c:folder\*.*) do application.exe /in:"%f" --log`

Comment: An NTFS formatted drive sorts by alphabet naturally but a FAT32 formatted drive needs to have a sort option specified.

Answer (score 1):

This script will launch all the applications in the current directory (in alphabetic order), wait for them to finish and then continue to the next one (%%a in a batch file and %a in cmd)

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /B /O:N^|findstr /L /I ".exe"') do ("%%a" /in:"c:folder\filename1.txt" --log)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use powershell and have used the below bit of code. It will loop through each script matching a pattern and will execute alphabetically. In this example we'll execute any powershell script:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Scripts" | Where `
    { $_.Name -like '*.ps1'} | ForEach `
    { . $_.FullName }
```

If you wanted to launch batch scripts you can do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Scripts" | Where `
    { $_.Name -like '*.bat'} | ForEach `
    { cmd.exe /c $_.FullName }
```